# How do I change the MAC address of my WLAN card?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac-address

I want to change the physical address because of a minor network issue, so I searched How to change Mac address with Google.

Since my WLAN card does not support changing the Mac address in the adapter settings of the control panel, I opened regedit and created a registry file called 'NetworkAddress' to write a new 12 digit MAC address that meets the hexadecimal notation.

However, I could not connected to the Internet after changing the Mac address. So I reseted the Mac address and the internet have connected. I can not connect to the Internet even though I entered 2 in the second digit of the changed MAC address. What is the workaround I do not need to buy the new WLAN card?

I use realtek WLAN card.

Comment: What is the "minor network issue"?

Comment: You need to rejoin your wireless network after changing the MAC address.  If you already did, try restarting your wireless router after making the change.  Also, if your wireless router for some reason only allows certain MAC addresses to associate (called "MAC filtering") then you have to add the new MAC to that list by logging into the router's admin interface.

Answer (score -1):

After you change the MAC address, the IP address could be not useful, because the IP address is related to the MAC address. Look at this picture. This is in DHCP server, and it is the same as other DHCP devices. 
[image]

So, you could need to release the IP address, and renew the IP lease.
1. use ipconfig /release to release the IP configuration
2. use ipconfig /renew to renew the IP configuration